# sorting data on x-axis in google line chart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using google line chart to plot data by timestamp(x-axis).

my problem is that the x-axis is not being sorted automatically by the google charting.

e.g. "15:45:23 678" data point which should be the first in the chart is being shown at #2. If I put it at the first place then it is fine. That means Google chart doesn't care about the data and it plots as it sees them.

The issue is that my data set is huge and sorting it based on x-axis data takes lot of time. is there any flag in the line chart which could sort it in the browser?

below is the sample data:

```
['x', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6'],

['15:48:13 744', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 

['15:45:23 678', 5, 17, 36, 3957, 20, 21], 

['15:48:18 749', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: The reason values on your x-axis are not being sorted is that the values are strings, so it assumes you are using discrete values rather than continuous values.  You could instead use timeofday types, which will be continuous values, so they will be sorted.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following function to sort the underlying DataTable:
`data.sort([{column: 0}]);`.
Column 0 indicates the x-axis.

This will sort the data in asc order, for desc use `data.sort([{column: 0, desc: true}]);`

You may also be interested in the `getSortedRows(sortColumns)` function.

More information about these functions can be read about here
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_sort
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getSortedRows